# Resolve a filename from another file

Tags: php, file, class-design

I can currently to the following:

```
class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }
}

class SuperClass {
  function __construct() {
    // this echoes "I'm SubClass and I'm extending SuperClass"
    echo 'I\'m '.get_class($this).' and I\'m extending '.__CLASS__;
  }
}
```

I would like to do something similar with the filenames (`__FILE__`, but dynamically evaluated); I would like to know what file the subclass resides in, from the superclass. Is it possible in any elegant way?

I know you could do something with [`get_included_files()`](http://fi.php.net/get_included_files), but that's not very efficient, especially if I have numerous instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Reflection.

```
$ref = new ReflectionObject($this);
$ref->getFileName(); // return the file where the object's class was declared
```

Answer (score 0):

Uh, not really, that I can think of.  Each subclass would need to have an explicitly implemented method that returned `__FILE__`, which completely defeats the point of inheritance in the first place.

I'm also really curious as to why something like this would be useful.

Comment: I'm creating a framework that should be able to tell apart two classes with the same names, and give them unique and consistent identifiers. Currently, I'm doing the pass-the-__FILE__-trick, and construct said identifier from the path. Namespaces could help, but they're a bit too new for my needs.

Comment: Now I'm really confused.  Two classes with the same name?  Won't you get a "Cannot redeclare class" error?  Or are you actually planning on meta-programming each file?

Comment: They wouldn't normally be declared at the same time from PHP's point of view, as they would be in different modules, but in the same application. This isn't a normal case (and probably bad design), but I want it to be supported (because of 3rd party stuff - think CakePHP's bakery).